# Append to URL once for redirection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, append, greasemonkey

I don't know any Javascript and I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script that, when visiting a certain website, adds some stuff to the URL so that it automatically redirects there. The website in question contains videos and pictures of people, and when clicking on someone I want it to automatically append the necessary link to do a pictures-only search. I've replaced the actual website in the code with a mockup since it is not appropriate for all ages. Here is what I have so far (note that the comment marks are supposed to be there and it still gets read):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        CostlyTwos Pictures Only
// @namespace   costlytwospo
// @description Automatically redirects to pictures-only when browsing CostlyTwos
// @include     http://www.costlytwos.com/html/a_links/*
// @include     www.costlytwos.com/html/a_links/*
// @version     1.0
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.href = window.location.href + "links/index1-default-pics.shtml";
```

That just repeatedly adds "links/index1-default-pics.shtml" to the end of the URL, indefinitely. I've also tried adding an if statement that checks if the word "default" is in the URL (the website's links are very consistent so no complicated checks are needed) in an effort to make it stop once it's been done. That code looked like this:

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf("default") != -1) {
window.location.href = window.location.href + "links/index1-default-pics.shtml";
}
```

However that does absolutely nothing, as if the script doesn't exist. Google has gotten me this far but as I don't know Javascript, I'm not sure where to go from here. A typical URL for this place when selecting someone looks like:

www.costlytwos.com/html/a_links/NameHere/

A pictures-only link for NameHere would look like:

www.costlytwos.com/html/a_links/NameHere/links/index1-default-pics.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That just repeatedly adds "links/index1-default-pics.shtml" to the end of the URL, indefinitely

This is because the script gets reloaded on each page you navigate to. When you complete the navigation, it calls the script again.

You had the right instinct to check if the URL was already in the right format. The problem is that the test is incorrect.

> `window.location.search.indexOf("default") != -1`

You're [accessing the search property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_5_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property) (the `?var=123` part of the URL) when what you probably want to look at is the `href` property:

```
window.location.href.indexOf("default") != -1
```

Even with this fix, if `default` shows up anywhere in the URL (like if someone's username contains "default"), then your script will not do the redirect. You might need to break down the URL into more parts (using something like [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)) before you can be sure your script is bug free. If you go down this route, using `window.location.pathname` would probably be better than the `window.location.href` property.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I changed search to href and it went back to doing nothing at all, but after I also changed the operator to == -1 it suddenly started working perfectly. The final code looks like this:

`if (window.location.href.indexOf("default") == -1) {
window.location.href = window.location.href + "links/index1-default-pics.shtml";
}`

Now it works like I expected it to. This is just for me and based on the way I browse the site in question, it'll do just fine. No need for me to clean it or squash bugs. Thanks again!